# Anyway to use quarkus-scheduler @Scheduled with rate under the second?

Tags: quarkus

I am trying to schedule something than need to be ran every 200ms:

```
@Scheduled(every = "0.2s")
```

What's the recommended way to do it?
Is there a good reason why `@Scheduled` doesn't support rate under the second?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not supported. The idea is that `@Scheduled` is only used for cron-like tasks with an accuracy of seconds (note that the Cron standard is designed to work with an accuracy of minutes).

However, you can inject a managed `Vertx` instance and make use of `Vertx.setPeriodic()`. But keep in mind that the handler is executed on an event loop thread and so the code should not block. If you really need to execute some blocking code then look at `Vertx.executeBlocking()`.

The plan is to add an injectable managed `ScheduledExecutorService` for similar use cases.

Comment: Thanks Martin :)

Comment: btw maybe `@Scheduled` should not _allow_ what it doesn't manage ? Current form is quite error-prone

Comment: Yes, the validation could be improved. Feel free to file an issue here: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues